# How to search pattern in certain range of text and replace with another string?

Tags: perl

```
$ NAME : corry   
$$.Inc s d  
$$.Oc s 
$$.TO

G1 ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU   
G2 n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU   
.EON  

$ NAME : patrick  
$$.Inc c d
$$.Oc c 
$$.TO 

G1 td n3 EE EE M T5 T6 $$SRU    
G2 n3 y OO OO M T7 T8 $$SRU  
.EON


$ NAME : danny

$$.Inc a b 
$$.Oc b
$$.TO 

@lc1 corry 
@lc2 patrick
1 to n0 EE EE M S1 S2 $$SRU
G2 n0 y OO OO M S3 S4 $$SRU   
.EON

$ NAME : sandy    
$$.Inc m n   
$$.Oc n
$$.TO   

G1 te n1 EE EE M b1 b2 $$SRU    
G2 n1 o OO OO M b3 b4 $$SRU    
.EON     


$ NAME : manager   
$$.Inc o e
$$.Oc e      
$$.TO    

@lc3 danny      
@lc4 sandy     
G1o ty n1 EE EE M T1 T2 $$SRU    
G2o n1 y OO OO M T3 T4 $$SRU   
.EON
```

How to search for a certain pattern in a certain range? For example, I want to search `G1o` at range between the section from `$ Name : manager` until the end of `End of name (.EON)` and replace it with `G1o.corry.n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/G1o/G1o.corry.n/ if /\$ NAME : manager/ .. /\.EON/' file
```

From [**perlop**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) documentation:

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.

Comment: Thanks. What if I need to do multiple lines substitution in the same section?

Comment: @user2865279 you can either `s///, s/// if ..` or `if (..) {s///; s///}`

Comment: Another question if you allow me. How to extract the certain part of the text and display it? For example, I want to output the section from $NAME : corry and $NAME : Manager.

Comment: Here's my code `use warnings; use strict; my $test; my @words; my $word; open(INFO,"<","testing.pl")||die"Can't open file:$!\n"; chomp (@words=<INFO>); close(INFO); foreach $word(@words){ if(/^\$ NAME : corry/ .. /\.EON/){ $test=$1; print $test; } }`
Nothing is print out for the text. May I know what is the problem?

Comment: How to ensure that I only print out selected certain section from the text? This is because `$ NAME : corry or $ NAME: Manager` have the same end line character which is `.EON`. I don't want the text print from corry until the last line of .EON in the text.

Comment: Try `foreach (@words){ if(/^\$ NAME : corry/ .. /\.EON/){ $test=$1; print $test; } }`

Comment: Sorry, I tried your suggestion but output nothing of the selection text.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^\$ NAME : manager/,/\.EON/s/G1o/G1o.corry.n/'
```